# How to create dynamic webscraper in Django using BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am trying to create a dynamic webscraper using Django.
I have an html page with buttons, so it is like when I will press the button it will start the webscraper and save the data in the database and later on by pressing another button I can download that data in CSV format.

Now I have prepared the html page for buttons.
I have written webscraper script and in my `views.py` I have imported that scraper file and called that function but when I type `python manage.py runserver` the scraper starts but my web page is not reachable.

First: how can I solve this problem?
Second: how can I connect my scraper with the html button?
Third: how I can save the data in the database?
Fourth: how can I download them into csv when I press the button?

Below is my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.http import HttpResponse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

import Up# this is the web scraping file

# Create your views here.

#def index(request):
#    first = {"here":"will enter more details"}
#    return render(request, "files/first-page.html", context=first)
    #return HttpResponse("<em>Rera details will be patched here</em>")    

#uncomment this below link to exectue scraper but html page will not be accessible

def scrapper_view(request):
    Up.scraper()#calling function here
    return HttpResponse("<em>Scraper Started</em>")
```

This my Html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<body>
</head>
<style>
table, th, td{
border: 1px solid black;
text-align:center;
}
</style>

<h1 style="background-color:rgb(180,180,180);">DOWNLOAD RERA RAW DATA FROM AVAILABLE SCRAPERS</h1>
<table align="center" style="width:45%">

<tr>
<th align="center"> State </th>
<th align="center"> Data</th>
<th align="center"> Agents</th>
<th align="center"> Download</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>MAHARASHTRA</td>

<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>GUJARAT</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>KARNATAKA</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>UTTRAKHAND</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>HIMACHAL PRADESH</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>UTTAR PRADESH</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>
<img src="{% static "images/joker.jpg" %}" alt="No images found">
<tr>
<td>MADHYA PRADESH</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<td>PUNJAB</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<td>DELHI/NCR</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<td>ODISHA</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<td>BIHAR</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<td>Kerala</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<td>Goa</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Start Crawling"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download"/></td>
</tr>   


</table>

</body>
</html>
```

UP is for Uttar Pradesh and the button I wish to attach to this scraper is start crawling in data column.

Can anyone please guide?